# How to remove react native package from android

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I'd uninstalled `react-native-reanimated`. Had `unlinked` it before removal.

Output:

```
> npx react-native unlink react-native-reanimated
warn Calling react-native unlink [packageName] is deprecated in favor of autolinking. It will be removed in the next major release.
Autolinking documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Unlinking "react-native-reanimated" iOS dependency
info iOS module "react-native-reanimated" has been successfully unlinked
info Android module "react-native-reanimated" is not installed
```

Followed by:

```
npm un react-native-reanimated
```

However, when I open the project in Android Studio, the package is still listed.

Where is configuration stored and how do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: check if the package is still listed in ```settings.gradle``` or ```MainApplication.java```

Answer (score 1):

To disable autolinking for a specific package you can define this in a `react-native.config.js` file.

```
   // react-native.config.js
    module.exports = {
      dependencies: {
        'some-unsupported-package': {
          platforms: {
            android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

More: [Disable autolinking for a specific library on different platforms](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library)

Answer (score -1):

1. Unlink - react native unlink react-native-reanimated.
2. Uninstall - react native uninstall react-native-reanimated.
3. Check in package.json, settings.gradle and MainApplication.java if the library or imports are still there.